# Sencha touch Cookies Class

Tags: cookies, sencha-touch, extjs

In Ext js 4.0, there is a "Cookies" class which we can use it to set and get cookies

In Sencha 2.0, there is no such class.

My question is how can I set cookies in Sencha touch 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Ext.util.Cookies is pretty simple. It doesn't look like it has any dependencies. If you have a license for Ext or your project is GPL, then I guess you could just copy it to your Touch project.

Comment: ok .. I tried it but when I do this set('ci','some value) .. Then i do get('ci') it works fine 
but when I enter another parameters like the domain, path, secure
e.g: Ext.util.Cookies.set('ci','90f3ln8nBnXDQC666421==',null,'/','www.myapp.com',true); ... the get returns null .. Why?